# Mongoose prevent field from being mass assigned

Tags: express, mongoose

So I have a field on a `User` schema that looks like the following:

```
admin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      select: false,
    }
```

But the problem is when creating a user like so:

`var user = await new User(req.body).save()`

I don't want the admin attribute to be set. I only want to be able to set it in one specific controller action for creating admin users. It would also be quite annoying to manually remove this field every time I create a user.

How can I do this with the least headache possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing strong parameters for my controllers, and only allow whitelisted parameters through. The case for blocking parameters is common enough that I needed it anyway.